# How to add menuItem from renderer process (browser window)

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm try out to do this with **remote**, but can't understand how it works =(

What I need to do:
1) ajax call to server (ok)
2) server response with 'issue123' (ok)
3) add 'issue123' in OS X standard menubar (how ?)

I create menuItem - Issues, and it's work correctly on loading app, but how I can push 'issue123' to this menu?

Answer (score 3):

After you add or remove a menu item in your menu you need to call `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` or `BrowserWindow.setMenu()` again to rebuild the native menu. However, there is no need to call the aforementioned methods again if you modify the `enabled`, `visible`, or `checked` properties on a menu item.

Sources:

- https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3940#issuecomment-168569389
- https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/937#issuecomment-67543939

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh... it's not easy for first time ;)

For example:
...

```
const trackerMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(trackerMenu);

const issuesMenu = trackerMenu.items[4]; //save your submenu item
```

...

```
success: function(data) { //my ajax callback

   let menuItem = new MenuItem({
     label: data,
     click: function(item, focusedWindow) {
       console.log(item)
     }
   })

   issuesMenu.submenu.insert(0, menuItem);
   Menu.setApplicationMenu(trackerMenu);
}
```